# Logical operators (AND, OR) with NA, TRUE and FALSE

Tags: r, logical-operators, r-faq

I cannot understand the properties of logical (boolean) values `TRUE`, `FALSE` and `NA` when used with logical OR (`|`) and logical AND (`&`). Here are some examples:

```
NA | TRUE
# [1] TRUE

NA | FALSE
# [1] NA

NA & TRUE
# [1] NA

NA & FALSE
# [1] FALSE
```

Can you explain these outputs?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To quote from `?Logic`:

> NA is a valid logical object. Where a component of x or y is NA, the
>   result will be NA if the outcome is ambiguous. In other words NA &
>   TRUE evaluates to NA, but NA & FALSE evaluates to FALSE. See the
>   examples below.

The key there is the word "ambiguous". `NA` represents something that is "unknown". So `NA & TRUE` could be either true or false, but we don't know. Whereas `NA & FALSE` will be false no matter what the missing value is.

Comment: I wish this reasoning extended beyond just the logical operators. Because NA as a valid logical object does not extend to unsigned operations. For instance, one could conceive that max(c(TRUE, NA)) should be TRUE because TRUE is the highest possible logical value.

Comment: @AdamO When the docs say that "NA is a valid logical object" it just means that there's a version of NA with a logical type. In a numeric vector an `NA` is really the `NA_real_` object. If you take seriously the position that `NA` represents "unknown" that also implies unknown type. So `max(c(TRUE, NA))` could be `max(c(TRUE,'Z'))` which would evaluate to `Z`.

Comment: but in this case a coercion happens because typeof('Z') is character whereas typeof(NA) is logical in my not-well-flushed-out example.

Comment: @AdamO Right, but the fact that `NA` is logical in that case doesn't represent any knowledge about what the missing value is, it's just a placeholder to be consistent with the type of the vector. The whole point is if a value is missing, you don't even know what it's type is.

Comment: this isn't true actually. `typeof(NA)` evaluates to logical. `typeof(0*NA)` evaluates to double!

Comment: @AdamO No, you're misunderstanding me. Just because the default logical typed NA is used doesn't mean that the *true* data value that is missing is logical. That's my point. The only reason the differently typed versions of NA exist is for internal type consistency & convenience. My point is that in the realm of real data sets, if a value is missing, that literally means you don't know what it is. Sometimes maybe you know it would have been numeric, but maybe not. So you can't assume that the NA in c(TRUE, NA) *must* be logical. It's just being represented that way in R for simplicity.

Answer (score 15):

It's explained in `help("|")`:

> `NA` is a valid logical object.  Where a component of `x` or `y`
>        is `NA`, the result will be `NA` if the outcome is ambiguous. In
>        other words `NA & TRUE` evaluates to `NA`, but `NA & FALSE`
>        evaluates to `FALSE`. See the examples below.

From the examples in `help("|")`:

```
x <- c(NA, FALSE, TRUE)
names(x) <- as.character(x)
outer(x, x, "&") ## AND table
#        <NA> FALSE  TRUE
# <NA>     NA FALSE    NA
# FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# TRUE     NA FALSE  TRUE

outer(x, x, "|") ## OR  table
#        <NA> FALSE TRUE
#  <NA>    NA    NA TRUE
# FALSE    NA FALSE TRUE
#  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
```