# Understanding when the && operator short circuits

Tags: r, short-circuiting

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious.

In R, `TRUE && NA` evalues to `NA`. This doesn't make sense to me, because `&&` should evaluate left to right, and stop as soon as one of its conditions is true.

Comment: It's touched on in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1535492/288545) but I still don't understand *why*

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844139/na-true-and-false-properties and especially @joran answer about ambiguity of `NA`.

Comment: AND requires both conditions to be true, so will only short-circuit on `FALSE`

Comment: http://spikedmath.com/445.html , http://mrburkemath.blogspot.ca/2011/05/coffee-logic.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> This doesn't make sense to me, because && should evaluate left to
>   right, and stop as soon as one of its conditions is true.

This is wrong. You are mixing up `&&` with `||`:

- `TRUE && FALSE` gives `FALSE`

  - && requires both conditions to be TRUE
  - `&&` will short-circuit on FALSE
- `TRUE || FALSE` gives `TRUE`

  - `||` requires a single condition to be TRUE
  - `||` will short-circuit on TRUE

Also,

```
TRUE || NA
```

gives

```
TRUE
```