# Check if a file exists on Amazon s3 through R on EC2 instance?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to check if a file exists on s3 through Rstudio on Amazon EC2 instance. Base R's `exists()` function and `file.exists()` functions are returning `FALSE` for every file. Following is my code, `exists.type` exists in s3 and `not_exists.type` does not exist.

```
library("aws.s3")
Sys.setenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" = "key1",
           "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" = "key2",
           "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" = "key3"
)

existing_file_path = "s3://bucket_name/folder_name/exists.type"
not_existing_file_path = "s3://bucket_name/folder_name/not_exists.type"

exists(existing_file_path) #returns FALSE
exists(not_existing_file_path) #returns FALSE

file.exists(existing_file_path) returns FALSE
file.exists(not_existing_file_path) returns FALSE

aws.s3::get_object(existing_file_path) #reads the entire file
aws.s3::get_object(not_existing_file_path) #gives error
```

I tried `list.files` also, it returns `character(0)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the function `head_object()`, which only returns metadata about your object without returning the object itself.

```
aws.s3::head_object("your_file", bucket = "your_bucket")
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `aws.s3::head_object`, but be careful with misleading return values. `aws.s3::head_object` will return `FALSE` when a connection couldn't be established as well as `FALSE` when a connection *could* be established, but the file couldn't be located.

I'd suggest you include some logic to determine whether the `FALSE` value that was returned was truly a missing file, or a potentially present file in an S3 bucket you can't access

```
obj_metadata <- aws.s3::head_object(object = "exists.type", bucket = "s3://bucket_name/")

if (!is.null(attr(obj_metadata, "connection")) && attr(obj_metadata, "connection") == "close") {
  stop("Could not establish connection with AWS S3")
}
```

### Explanation

The returned attributes for each of the three common return values are quite different from one another. For example, a `True` return value comes with attributes like:

- $`last-modified`
- $etag
- $`x-amz-server-side-encryption`
- $`accept-ranges`
- $`content-length`

While an invalid connection is the only return value with this attribute:

```
$connection
[1] "close"
```

I'll note as well that a valid `False` return value (when you establish a connection and the file doesn't exist) contains a subset of the `True` return attributes.

So assuming you want to halt a program when a connection couldn't be established, I'd recommend to first check that the `$connection` attribute exists with

```
!is.null(attr(obj_metadata, "connection"))
```

Then to be extra safe, may as well check that the value of said connection is "close" with:

```
attr(not_exists, "connection") == "close"
```

Note I use `&&` instead of `&` because it's a [short circuit operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844418/understanding-when-the-operator-short-circuits) given a previous `FALSE` value. The second conditional statement on an existing file would return `logical(0)`, thus raising an error.

For reference, [Python's top voted answer for the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33843019/11550733) uses a similar intuition