# Why does any() return NA when no true values

Tags: r

So we have this behaviour:

```
any(c(TRUE, FALSE, NA))
#> [1] TRUE
any(c(TRUE, NA))
#> [1] TRUE
any(c(FALSE, NA))
#> [1] NA
```

Anyone know the rationale for returning NA instead of FALSE? IMO the function should be testing for presence of non-FALSE values, which NA is not.

Comment: Because `FALSE|NA` returns NA

Comment: From the values section of the help file: "The value returned is TRUE if at least one of the values in x is TRUE, and FALSE if all of the values in x are FALSE (including if there are no values). Otherwise the value is NA."

Comment: Use `any(na.omit(c(FALSE, NA)))` to always get TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: We also have `na.rm` parameter in `any`.  Set it to `TRUE` to remove `NA`'s.

Comment: For what it's worth, R's behavior is quite sensible if you conscider that NA is an unknown value, and could therefore be TRUE or FALSE. This is why `c(TRUE, NA)` is determined, but `c(FALSE, NA)` is not.

Comment: Also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1535492/4341440).

Comment: Because `NA` is an _unknown_ value and, being in a `logical` vector, it _might_ be either `TRUE` or `FALSE`. So, when you ask `any(c(FALSE, NA))`, R can't tell anything: the answer might be any, depending on the actual value of the second element.

Comment: Background reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)

Comment: The [relevant source code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/af7f52f70101960861e5d995d3a4bec010bc89e6/src/main/logic.c#L392-L399), called by [do_logic3](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/af7f52f70101960861e5d995d3a4bec010bc89e6/src/main/logic.c#L452), which determines the behavior of these expressions: `any(c(TRUE, NA)); any(c(FALSE, NA)); all(c(FALSE, NA)); all(c(TRUE, NA))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behavior is explained in the values section of the help file:

> The value returned is TRUE if at least one of the values in x is TRUE, and FALSE if all of the values in x are FALSE (including if there are no values). Otherwise the value is NA.

As you note, this seems to differ from the behavior of more commonly used functions such as `sum` and `mean`, since the presence of NA values in vector arguments to these functions return NA. This problem in perception is cleared up by [joran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16844214/4895725) which refers to the documentation from `?Logic`, to requote:

> NA is a valid logical object. Where a component of x or y is NA, the result will be NA if the outcome is ambiguous. In other words NA & TRUE evaluates to NA, but NA & FALSE evaluates to FALSE. See the examples below.

So in the case of ambiguity, for example, the calculation of a mean where the vector contains NA, or `NA | FALSE` where the missing value might be TRUE, NA will be the output. Whereas in other cases such as `any(c(TRUE, NA))` or `TRUE | NA`, the outcome is unambiguous despite the presence of a missing value. This logic may be clearer in @Floo0's answer and in some of the comments to the question.

Answer (score 5):

I might be mistaken but the logic here is:

`NA` means unknown value. So the question

> Is any of value of (`FALSE`, `NA`) true?

Is answered with "I dont know" aka `NA` because `NA` could be `TRUE` but it is unknown at the moment you are asking.

Take the question

> Is any value of (`TRUE`, `NA`) true?

This is answered with `TRUE` as certainly the first value is `TRUE`.

Comment: This is actually the answer (made a similar comment, whose content is actually what @Axeman said before me).

Comment: @nicola: Sorry i didn't see your comment... You want me to delete my answer and answer yourself?

Comment: Not at all. This answer needs to be here, since in my opinion the accepted answer doesn't stress the reasons why this is totally expected. It matters very little who posted it.

Answer (score 4):

I would wrap the call in `isTRUE`, this yields the desired result:

```
> any(c(FALSE, NA))
[1] NA
> isTRUE(any(c(FALSE, NA)))
[1] FALSE
```

From the documentation:

> ‘isTRUE(x)’ is an abbreviation of ‘identical(TRUE, x)’, and so is
>        true if and only if ‘x’ is a length-one logical vector whose only
>        element is ‘TRUE’ and which has no attributes (not even names).