# How do I eliminate rows with certain values in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I am trying to eliminate the rows in my dataset that have as values of the variable income either 0 or NA. By running the two lines of code below, I found out that there are 1039 observations with the characteristics that I am looking for. In particular, even though I am only asking for income equal to 0, r automatically takes into also the NA values.

```
length(allregions$income[allregions$emp == 1 & allregions$income == 0])
allregions$income[allregions$emp == 1 & allregions$income == 0]
```

However, when I try to eliminate those rows, r only deletes the rows with income equal to 0 and keeps those with NA. Even if I add NA in the condition, those values still remain in my dataset.

```
allregions <- allregions[!(allregions$income == 0 & allregions$emp == 1),]
```

How can I drop the rows with NAs in a particular column?
Also, how is it possible that even though I apply the same condition, in one case R takes into account NAs too and in another it doesn't?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) along with the expected output?

Comment: Use ```which(...)``` around your filtering statement. ```which``` returns the indices which are TRUE. You can also look into ```na.omit()```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `%in%` like this:

```
result <- allregions[!(allregions$income %in% c(0, NA)), ]
```

Or use `is.na()` to test for `NA`

```
result <- allregions[allregions$income != 0 & !is.na(allregions$income), ]
```

To understand *why* R behaves like it does, I'd suggest these FAQs: [Logical operators (AND, OR) with NA, TRUE and FALSE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16844139/903061), [Dealing with TRUE, FALSE, NA and NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16822426/903061)

Answer (score 1):

[Tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/) is a great package for this sort of task:

```
library(tidyverse)

result <- allregions %>%
  filter(!is.na(income) & income !=0)

result <- allregions %>%
  filter(!income %in% c(0, NA))
```